# increment with 2 decimal in VBA becomes infinite .99999999

Tags: vba

I am having these codes with

`cells(4,9)=0, cells(4,10)=1, cells(4,11)=0.01`

in the sheet:

```
AF_from = Cells(4, 9).Value
AF_to = Cells(4, 10).Value
af_jump = Cells(4, 11).Value

For x = AF_from To AF_to Step af_jump
Cells(19, 8).Value = x
```

then the result is 0, 0.01,0.02,0.03...as expected until 0.83, then unexpected results 0.839999, 0.849999, 0.859999...1.999998

What should I do to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I wouldn't use a `For` loop using `Double` types. Explaining a little bit better: counters are ok when you use an `Integer`or`Long` but you may encounter problems if you use fractions.
You could multiply your `af_jump` and `AF_to` (in this case by 100) and use those. Then write `Cells(19, 8).Value = x/100`.

You need also to be sure that all those variables have been set to their correct type. **Especially** the `x` which if not, will reproduce numbers as 0.84 like 0.8399999999. That is the "normal" way vba calculates. This is due to a finite bit precision.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info

Assuming this is Excel, set the number format to two decimals.